# How do you pass a function to itself a variable number of times to form an "n level method call"?

Tags: c#, random, methods, call

Suppose we have the bare bones C# code for random number generation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace theBlindPainterTester
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random randomNumber = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            randomNumber.Next(1, 6);
        }
    }
}
```

We could easily call Next() on itself to set the upper bound.

```
randomNumber.Next(1, randomNumber.Next(1, 6));
```

This could be referred to as a two level method call, a "random number between 1 and (a random number between 1 and 5)."  Similarly we could write a three level method call.

```
randomNumber.Next(1, randomNumber.Next(1, randomNumber.Next(1, 6)));
```

How can we do this for N levels, where N is a variable not known until run time?  I've attempted to mold out the logic using a recursive method, but it seems you would need to call Next() on every iteration for that to work, which requires immediate knowledge of parameters.  Perhaps I'm just not thinking about it the correct way.

Comment: You want to generate a random number between a lower and upper bound. Since you know the lower bound value, choose the largest upper bound value and use that. You are making it complicated

Comment: I think a for loop could do that. A For loop for N levels;
var Rnd = 0; for(var i=0; i< N; i++){ rnd = randomNumber.Next(1,randomNumber.Next(1, 6)) } then you could call randomNumber.Next(1,Rnd)

Comment: @Smac89 That is not what the questions is asking, and would not produce results with the same probability (even though the range would be the same).

Comment: @user10478, the more times you use the same lower bound but keep decreasing you upper bound, the closer the values will get to the lower bound

Comment: @Smac89 re "the closer the values will get to the lower bound", how can you assert that?

Comment: Not sure who is right or wrong, but in his statement of upper bound decreasing, and lower staying the same, it's mathematically logical that values will approach the lower bound- what other direction would they go?

Comment: Tending toward the lower bound is the desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
r = 6;
for (int k = 0; k < N; k++)
    r = randomNumber.Next(1, r);
```

Comment: I've been staring at this for a while- can you explain it? It's interesting looking and not clicking.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who's been staring.  =P

Comment: This is the non-recursive approach.  "r" gets reset on every iteration through the loop.  You loop "N" times, where N is set at run time.  Personally, I'd prefer recursion.  But this should work just fine, I believe.

Comment: @alykins Well, let's just take OP's sample, `N=3`. On the first step, we calculate the rightmost `Next`, i.e. `randomNumber.Next(1, 6)`, and it is now `r`. On the second step, we calculate the second `Next`, using `r` from step one. And finally, on the third step, we get the answer.

Comment: @DeadZone Why do you prefer recursion? Iteration (in this case) looks shorter and faster, it also does not use extra stack space.

Comment: @AlexD - Code readability.  Using recursion would make it obvious that the intention is to use the result of the previous call as the input to the next call.  Yes, it consumes more resources, but in this example, the difference is probably not significant.  Using this method, unless you had a good comment, other developers might not recognize the intention of the code, or might need to "stare at it for a while" to figure it out.  (I certainly wouldn't complain if I saw this code in an application, somewhere.)

Comment: @DeadZone I do not insist, but for me the iterative process is also simpler to understand than recursion. I agree that the resource consumption is not the decisive argument in our case perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this work?

```
private int Generate(int Counter)
{
    if (Counter>0)
        return randomnumber.Next(1, Generate(Counter-1));
    else
        return randomnumber.Next(1, 6);
}
```